# Through handle_in in channel to insert data into database

Tags: phoenix-framework, channel, ecto

I have a table for tables and orders. Relationship between order and table is that `Order` is belong to table and table has many orders. So there is `table_id` in one of columns of order table. And also table has a column of `current_order` to keep current `order_id` that table currently has.

I have a `table:show` channel, which shows all lists of tables. And when a user clicks a table, it pushes `table:busy` and sends `table_id` of clicked table.

So, in the table channel, there is handle_in for `table:busy` and I want to create order with `table_id` which sent from `table:show` channel.

```
def handle_in("table:busy", %{"table_id" => table_id}, socket) do
    table = Repo.get(Pos1.Table, table_id)
    changeset = table
        |> assoc(:orders)
        |> Pos1.Order.changeset(:table_id)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
        {:ok, order}->
    changesettable = Table.changeset(table, %{current_order: order.id})
    table = Repo.update!(changesettable)
    {:noreply, socket}

    {:error, changeset} ->
        {:reply, {:error, %{error: "Error creating order"}}, socket}

    end

end
```

This is the error message:

```
---[error] GenServer #PID<0.1327.0> terminating
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Query.__changeset__/0 is undefined or private
    (ecto) Ecto.Query.__changeset__()
    (ecto) Ecto.Changeset.do_cast/4
    (pos1) web/channels/table_channel.ex:18: Pos1.TableChannel.handle_in/3
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:225: anonymous fn/4 in Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
```

Above error shows that changeset is not defined... How can I define the changeset to insert data into `Orders` table?

Thanks in advance..

---EDIT 1

```
defmodule Pos1.Order do
 use Pos1.Web, :model

schema "orders" do

field :number_of_customers, :integer
field :completed, :boolean, default: false
field :confirmed, :boolean, default: false
field :service_charge, :boolean, default: true
field :total, :integer, default: 0
field :discount, :float, default: 0.0
field :current_select, :integer, default: 1
field :payed, :float
field :finalized, :boolean, default: false
field :served, :boolean, default: false
field :current_round, :integer, default: 0
field :rounds, :integer, default: 1
field :created_date, Ecto.DateTime
belongs_to :table, Pos1.Table
belongs_to :payment, Pos1.Payment
has_many :order_items, Pos1.OrderItem
belongs_to :staff, Pos1.Staff

timestamps
end

  @required_fields ~w(number_of_customers table_id completed confirmed 
                  total service_charge current_select finalized served
                  rounds current_round)
  @optional_fields ~w(payment_id discount staff_id payed created_date)


 def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
   model
   |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Comment: Which line from the above is line 18? Or is the that the whole handle in function? If it is, it might be because it's getting confused with the `changeset` variable. Maybe try changing it to be `order_changeset` instead of just `order`.

Comment: line 18 is `|> Pos1.Order.changeset(:table_id)`..

Comment: hmm thats odd. Are you able to add your order model or at least the order changeset?

Comment: Yes, if I try to make an order without channel, it works fine by using `create action`.. but I want to make an order when a user pushes channel `table:busy`..

Comment: oops i meant add the actual code for the `web/models/order.ex` (or wherever you put it)

Comment: Yes, for now, i have `Orders` model and controller. But the reason why I want to use channel for creating order is that I have an index page which shows all tables. And I want each of table to change color when a table has an order in real time... So i created channel `TableChannel` and topic of `tableshow` to send and receive messages of `table:busy` to show whether the table is busy or not...

Comment: yeah I understand that and it should be possible. I'm asking you to had the code from your order model to the original question so I can see if there is anything wrong with it or why that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by `@required_fields` of `Orders` model.

I did not pass every `@required_fields` so it did not create an order.

I moved some `@required_fields` to `@optional_fields` and it worked.